# moving a numbered amount of named items from one array into another

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not exactly sure how the logic would work on this. My brain is fried and i cant think clearly.

I am handling some POST data, and one of the fields in this array is a quantity string. I can read this string and determine if there are more than 1 widgets that need handled.

```
if($quantity <= 1){ //$_POST[widget1] }
```

Now say there are 4 widgets. The quantity field would reflect this number, but how would i loop through them and assign them to a new array themselves?

```
$_POST[widget1], $_POST[widget2], $_POST[widget3], $_POST[widget4]
```

How do i take that quantity number, and use it to grab that many and those specific named items from the post array, using some kind of wild card or prefix or something? I dont know if this is a `for`, or `while`, or what kind of operation. How do I loop through $_POST['widget**X**'], where X is my quantity number?

The end result is im looking to have an array structured like this:

```
$widgets[data1]
$widgets[data2]
$widgets[data3]
$widgets[data4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `for` loop, you can access the `$_POST` keys with a variable, as in `$_POST["widget$i"]`

```
$widgets = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=$quantity; $i++) {
  // Append onto an array
  $widgets[] = $_POST["widget$i"];
}
```

However, a better long-term solution would be to change the HTML form such that it passes an array back to PHP in the first place by adding `[]` to the form input's `name` attribute:

```
<input type='text' name='widgets[]' id='widget1' value='widget1' />
<input type='text' name='widgets[]' id='widget2' value='widget2' />
<input type='text' name='widgets[]' id='widget3' value='widget3' />
```

Accessed in PHP via `$_POST['widgets']`, already an array!

```
var_dump($_POST['widgets']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the number of items, at least over one (as you describe it):

```
$widgets = array();
foreach (range(1, max(1, $quantity)) as $item)
{
    $name = sprintf('widget%d', $item);
    $data = sprintf('data%d', $item);
    $widget = $_POST[$name];
    // do whatever you need to do with that $widget.
    $widgets[$data] = $widget;
}
```