# reading multiple values from text field in php

Tags: php, html

I 150 text fields in a form and I want to read the values when the form submitted. Do I have to write like below or there is any other short way...

```
$a1 = $_POST['a1']
$a2 = $_POST['a2']
$a3 = $_POST['a3']
$a4 = $_POST['a4']
$a5 = $_POST['a5']
----
----
----
$a150 = $_POST['a150']
```

I have printed all the text fields in form in using for loop in a form with name a1,a2,a3 and so on. I am wrinting as below but not workng

```
if (isset($_POST['save_exit']))
{

for ($j=1; $j<=150; $j++)
{
    ${a.$j} = $_POST['a'.$j];
}

    echo $a1;
}
```

but echo is not printing any value..

Comment: Rather make your form input a list with the syntax `<input name="text[]">` so you'll get an array without workarounds.

Comment: i would change the form so the fields where `name="xx[]"` the [] lets php create a nice array to loop through

Comment: See also [POSTing Form Fields with same Name Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2203430)

Comment: possible duplicate of [moving a numbered amount of named items from one array into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942068/moving-a-numbered-amount-of-named-items-from-one-array-into-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some neat stuff with php.  To do what you want, just use a loop like this:

```
$post_array[] = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 150; $i++)
{
    if (isset($_POST["a$i"]))
    {
        $post_array[] = $_POST["a$i"];
    }
} 
if (count(post_array) < 5)
{
   echo "not validated";
}
```

Comment: It depends what you mean by validating.  Do you mean to verify something is in each variable?  Then it is easy.  What are you validating?

Answer (score 2):

change this line:

```
 ${a.$j} = $_POST['a'.$j];
```

to:

```
 ${"a".$j} = $_POST['a'.$j];
```

if you want to print, then just use:

```
echo ${"a".$j} = $_POST['a'.$j];
```

Comment: Thank u .. its niceee//

Comment: You should check his answer as the one you wanted then! :)

Comment: your answer also correct dear.. but you have more points that the one who have answer below.. so I tick answer... sorry but Your answer gave me good information...

Comment: @user2642907 You can "upvote" Akam's answer also, by clicking the UP arrow, if you found it useful :)

Comment: @user2642907 OK, I will do it with your blessing then, in your name :) Cheers, *peace*.

Comment: @user2642907 I upvoted your question also, because I found it useful. And I think you might have enough points to upvote, but am not 100% sure about that.